# Riemann curvature in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, curvature

### Riemann Curvature in Quantum Mechanics

My understanding of the Riemann curvature is the following. We start with a vector take it around in a loop and ask ourselves what is the difference between the original vector and the looped vector divided by the area of the loop as it tends $\to 0$.

I was wondering if something similar already existed in structure of quantum mechanics. Namely,

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta a, \delta  t \to 0} \frac{|x \rangle - U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) U(\delta t)  T(\delta a) |x \rangle}{\delta a \delta t} $$

Where $ R_{a,t}$ is the Riemann Curvature of the $|x \rangle $, $T$ is the translation operator and $U$ is the unitary operator and $\delta t$ and $\delta a$ are infitesimal shifts in our parallelogram. We can do the following manulplation using $ U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) T( \delta a) U( \delta t) = I$

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta  a, \delta  t \to 0} \frac{ U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) T( \delta a) U( \delta t) |x \rangle - U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) U(\delta t)  T(\delta a) |x \rangle}{\delta a \delta t} $$

Or:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta  a,\delta  t \to 0} \frac{ U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \Big( T( \delta a) U( \delta t) - T( \delta a)+ T( \delta a) - I - U(\delta t)  T(\delta a) + U(\delta t) -U(\delta t) + I  \Big) |x \rangle}{\delta a \delta t} $$

Again taking common factors:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta  a, \delta  t \to 0} \frac{ U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \Big( T( \delta a) (U( \delta t) - I)+ T( \delta a) - I - U(\delta t) ( T(\delta a) - I) -U(\delta t) + I  \Big) |x \rangle}{\delta a \delta t} $$

Using the definition of momentum $p$ and the Hamiltonian $H$ from translation operators:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta  a,\delta  t \to 0} U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \Big( \frac{-i }{\hbar }  \frac{T( \delta a) ( H )}{\delta a}+ \frac{-i }{\hbar } \frac{p}{\delta t} + \frac{i }{\hbar } U(\delta t) ( \frac{p}{\delta t}) + \frac{i}{\hbar} \frac{H}{\delta a} \Big) |x \rangle $$

Taking $i / \hbar$ and other factors common:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta  a,\delta  t \to 0} U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \frac{i }{\hbar }\Big( -  \frac{T( \delta a) ( H )}{\delta a}-  \frac{p}{\delta t} +U(\delta t) ( \frac{p}{\delta t}) + \frac{H}{\delta a} \Big) |x \rangle $$

Again applying definitions of position and momentum:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle = \lim_{\delta a, \delta t \to 0} U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \frac{i }{\hbar } \frac{- i }{\hbar }\Big(H p - p H \Big) |x \rangle $$

Now using Heisenberg's equation of motion this is nothing more than the rate of change of momentum and trivially $U(- \delta t) T( - \delta a) \to 0$:

$$ R_{a,t} |x \rangle =  \frac{i }{\hbar } \dot p |x \rangle $$

### Question

Obviously I can't be the first person who thought of doing this. Is there some papers or book or good exposition which runs along a similar thought and tries to think about the geometry of quantum mechanics in a similar fashion? Also is there any implication of this operator being anti-hermicitian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Riemann curvature observable in quantum mechanics. So, no. Riemann curvature is a property of spacetime, not of the state of a particle. Indeed, a measurement of Riemann curvature actually requires multiple measurements of different (classical) particles at different positions --- this is a matter of principle. No practical measurement has been proposed, and if it were proposed, it would not involve quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked through your math, but your idea sounds the *[Berry phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase)*.